# onsen-ui: pushing a page already on the stack

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I'm trying to display users and the posts they created. The user can search for posts, then click one of these posts. This post page will have a link to the user's profile that created that post...and this user's profile has a link to all his posts...which in turn can be clicked on to see another post's details.

So now I end up needing to push a page that is already on the stack. I use app.navi.pushPage to first initially push searchResults, then I push postDetails (for a given postid), then userProfile, then usersPosts, then postDetails again (for a different postid). What ends up happening is this second instance of postDetails is blank and is not initialzied by the ng-controller. If I keep hitting back I see that the original first postDetails page has been modified slighlty with the contents I expect to see on the second postDetails page I pushed.

Essentially what I have is this:

```
app.navi.pushPage("searchResults");
app.navi.pushPage("postDetails"); //first instance
app.navi.pushPage("userProfile");
app.navi.pushPage("usersPosts");
app.navi.pushPage("postDetails"); //second instance with different init params...not initializing properly
```

How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do? I need to push two instances of postDetails with different initialization parameters...and I need the two instances to remain unique. I need to be able to hit back from the second page all the way back also...so I can't just delete the first instance using resetToPage.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I can get access to the current page even if it is the second instance by using the following:

```
    var currentPage = app.navi.getCurrentPage();
    var jCurrentPage = jQuery(currentPage.element);
```

Then I can use jCurrentPage to access elements on that specific instance of the page and set it to whatever it needs to be....and if I use back button the first instance of the page remains intact.

Answer (score 0):

```js
ons.bootstrap()
.controller('detailCtrl', function($scope){
  var options = $scope.navi.getCurrentPage().options;
  $scope.id = options.id;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

<ons-navigator var="navi" page="index">
</ons-navigator>

<ons-template id="index">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
      <div class="center">index</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <ons-button ng-click="navi.pushPage('list')">show list</ons-button>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="list">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
      <div class="center">list</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <ons-list>
      <ons-list-item ng-repeat="id in [1,2,3]" ng-click="navi.pushPage('detail', {id: id})">
        id: {{id}}
      </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="detail">
  <ons-page ng-controller="detailCtrl">
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
      <div class="center">detail</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <div>
      id: {{id}}
    </div>
    <ons-button ng-click="navi.pushPage('list')">show list</ons-button>
  </ons-page>
  
</ons-template>
```

Here is a working example. It uses `ng-controller` and the second argument of `navi.pushPage()` as initializing parameters.

Comment: no thats not what i'm looking for....i know how to pass parameters to a page. My point is, the second time I push postDetails I pass in a different option parameter, and it doesn't initialize properly....where as the first time works perfectly fine

Comment: You can go `index` -> `list` -> `detail` -> `list` -> `detail` ...  in the above example. and the value of `$scope.id` is different in each `detail` page. Is this not what you want to do?